# How do I let users point to their own images, yet avoid Mixed Content warnings?

Tags: tls, image, css, mixed-content

I allow users of my webapp to provide a URL for their own images. They can also provide CSS which may contain URLs to images.

If these URLs are `HTTP` then the browser does not show the padlock in the URL bar.

What is the best practice for avoiding this?

- Rewriting `HTTP` addresses as `HTTPS`, including URLs inside CSS? (Perhaps, after checking that the resource exists at the `HTTPS` address.)
- Rejecting any URL that is not `HTTPS`?
- Copying the image or CSS (with its referenced images) into my system? (This would mean, for better or worse, that the content would not change as the original does.)

Comment: @Joshua Jones Thank you for the edit. Is it OK if I leave URL, URLs, image-URL in default font. It seems that the usage of those words is English rather than a direct code reference (so we *would* have HTTP and HTTPS in code font).

Comment: Yes - it's your question :) I just wanted to neaten it.

Comment: I would reject anything not using HTTPS. Let the user host their images on a server with HTTPS.

Comment: @ThoriumBR so, we would also scan the CSS and reject it if any HTTP links are in it?

Comment: Yes, scan the CSS and if any `http`, `ftp`, `gopher` or whatever else is found, reject and throw an informative error message.

Answer (score 5):

> Would rewriting HTTP addresses as HTTPS work?

Only if the webserver hosting the images accepts https as well as http.

I would say the solution is to grab the images, and host a copy yourself, which you serve to your clients. Take the URL (or parse the CSS for images), download a copy, and substitute.

Comment: This is also how eg. bulletin board softwares nowdays do this, with a cache that expires after some days.

Comment: @user155462 Yes, I won't really claim it's my original idea :)

Comment: It wasn't meant like that :D Just that this is a usable good solution

Comment: @user155462 This will avoid Mixed Content warnings, but it will also  create the same vulnerability as just using the  user's to provide HTTP links. Whenever that cache expires, the attacker has the opportunity to interpose fake images, right? 

At least if you grab the image when the URL is  first  given, the user has the opportunity to see if the resulting image is the expected one.

Comment: @JoshuaFox IMO adding fake images for the given URL is a different question from just ensuring that you get a padlock on the browser. If you want to ensure no MITM as well, please either post a different question or update your existing question. I vote for a new question

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Security Policy with directive [upgrade-insecure-requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests):
`Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;`

Browsers will internally replace all http: requests to https: one. [Here](https://csplite.com/csp/test224/) you can cee how it works, just open Dev Tool console.

Also you can use `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: block-all-mixed-content; report-uri /csp_endpoint` to find all mixed content, but you neet to get CSP violation reports somewhere (/csp_endpoint).